# Getting web.config details in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, class-library

I am working on an asp .net project in which I wrote a custom library for the logging of data. I am planning to refer this class library in my project and I need to pass some details like filename, filepath etc and from the web project to the class library.

Since this information will change usually, I am planning to give this data in web.config file in the web project. I can read this configuration file data and pass the info to the class library.

Is it possible to pass the whole configuration object to class library and read from there?

Comment: When you use a class library, it becomes part of your application and can access Configuration just like code directly in the ASP.NET site. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. Ideally your class library would have some entry points where it gets configured, and your website would configure the class library as part of the startup process.

Comment: But I am planning to make this logger as a reusable component which is independent of a single project.

Comment: Just because you configure it from the website doesn't mean it's not independent. You can configure from whatever other project you add it to. But yes, if you want to read the Configuration directly in the class library, then go ahead! Have you tried? What's preventing you from doing it?

Comment: No I did't tried that.  I just want to make sure that it is not a bad way of coding. I will try that for sure. Thank you mason for you help.

Answer (score 0):

In web config add in "configuration" section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="logpath" value="c:\logs\log.txt" />
</appSettings>
```

And in code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logpath"]
```